# Error map reduce.(output empty of job mapp reduce)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to write code in java of map reduce.

The code gave me an empty file as output.

When I debugged it in mapper all is fine, but in the reducer when I do:

```
System.out.println("Reducer3: key = " + key);
```

It is not showing anything. This this my code:

Arbre class:

```java
package TP6;

public  class Arbre
{
    /* Les champs sont
     *  0: Geo point 
     *  1: ARRONDISSEMENT 
     *  2: GENRE 
     *  3: ESPECE 
     *  4: FAMILLE 
     *  5: ANNEE PLANTATION 
     *  6: HAUTEUR 
     *  7: CIRCONFERENCE 
     *  8: ADRESSE 
     *  9: NOM COMMUN 
     * 10: VARIETE 
     * 11: OBJECTID 
     * 12: NOM_EV 
     */
    static String[] champs;
    public static void fromLine(String ligne)
    {
        champs = ligne.split(";");
    }
    
    public static String getGenre()
    {
        return champs[2];
    }
    
    public static double getAnnee() throws Exception
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(champs[5]);
    }
    
    public static double getHauteur() throws Exception
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(champs[6]);
    }
    public static  String getArrondissement()throws Exception{
        return champs[1];
    }
    public static  String getAnnePlantation()throws Exception{
        return champs[5];
    }
}
```

Mapper class:

```java
package TP6;
    
import TP6.Arbre; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    
import javax.naming.Context; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Iterator; 
public class Mapper3 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, ArrayList<Object>>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String val = value.toString();
        Arbre.fromLine(val);
    
        try {
            String arrondissement = Arbre.getArrondissement();
            String anne = Arbre.getAnnePlantation();
            int age = 2023 - Integer.parseInt(anne);
            ArrayList<Object> item = new ArrayList<>();
            item.add(Integer.parseInt(arrondissement));
            item.add(age);
    
            context.write(new Text(arrondissement), item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

Reducer class:

```java
package TP6;
    
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
    
import javax.naming.Context; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
public class Reducer3 extends Reducer<Text,ArrayList<Object>,IntWritable,IntWritable> {
    int keymax = 0;
    int maxAge = 0;
    IntWritable cle=new IntWritable(); IntWritable valeur=new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<ArrayList<Object>> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
        System.out.println("hello");
        try {
            System.out.println("Reducer3: key = " + key);
    
    
    
            if (!values.iterator().hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Reducer3: values is empty");
                return;
            }
    
            for (ArrayList<Object> value : values) {
                int arrondissement = (int) value.get(0);
                int age = (int) value.get(1);
    
                if (age > maxAge) {
                    maxAge = age;
                    keymax = arrondissement;
                    cle.set(keymax);
                    valeur.set(maxAge);
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println("Reducer3: keymax = " + keymax + ", maxAge = " + maxAge);
            context.write(cle,valeur);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Main class:

```java
package TP6;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
    
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "arbre old");
        job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Mapper3.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Reducer3.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer3.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    
    }

}
```

I am try to exectue job map reduce, but the output is empty?

Comment: Are you sure the mapper is all fine? Does the jobtracker show that it's outputting mapper records? Having `Arbre.fromLine(val);` outside of the `try/catch` seems risky as any invalid data isn't going to be handled.

Comment: 1) Your catch block is empty. So you're ignoring all exceptions in the mapper. Reducer never runs if mapper outputs nothing 2) Arraylist is not a Writeable type that can be serialized in a mapper. Besides, you're only ever adding one item to that list at a time, so why use it? Note: You imported ArrayWritable, but never use it.. 3) you might want to use `class Arbre implements Writable`